# Getting Mongo to Connect to Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Yosemite Mongo user working through a MEAN book.  I've been following the steps exactly, but the MongoDB isn't connecting as expected.  I installed Mongo once before to mess around with importing data, but didn't get too far.  Below is all the Mongo related code I have besides package.json:

In app.js I have `require('./app_server/models/db');` and in that folder I have:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/Loc8r';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});
```

I am expecting to get

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/Loc8r
```

But instead get:

```
Mongoose disconnected
Mongoose connection error: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

I've tried changing a line to `var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:3000/Loc8r';` because that's what my computer is using, but then get this error:

```
Mongoose disconnected
Mongoose connection error: Error: connection closed
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Simple stuff first... are you sure mongo is running?

Comment: I'm not sure?  The book didn't say anything about running it as a step.

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: Mac Yosemite.  Added to post

Comment: I'm absolutely shocked that your book did not say to start the mongo server before attempting to connect to it. Also, when you start it, you'll need to customize it to listen on port 3000 (27017 is the default).

Comment: I am trying to run "mongod" but get "ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo" .   Also tried "mongod --dbpath /data/db" but that doesn't work. Is that the data directory I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo was missing the folders it needed [MongoDB not working. "ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599119/mongodb-not-working-error-dbpath-data-db-does-not-exist)

Then the server had to be run with "mongod"